# How to put a 3rd party server control inside a custom server control in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, custom-server-controls

I am using Telerik ASP.Net Ajax controls (theoretically shouldn't matter who makes the 3rd party control). I would like to create my own custom server control (not user control) that has my own predefined HTML output but also includes a Telerik DatePicker. Since the Telerik DatePicker is another server control **what is the correct procedure to place a server control into my custom server control**.

My understanding is that server controls work by writing html output. How can I write the output of another control that I instantiate in the Render method and still retain the original controls individual lifecycle.

Desired outcome:

- My own custom server control that contains many 3rd party controls (ie. RadDatePicker).

**Solution**

Thanks to @Sumo for pointing me into the direction of the Composite control. Documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol.aspx).

I was able to solve the issue by creating a control that inherits `CompositeDataBoundControl`. Then databinding my datasource, calculating how many custom controls needed, placing them into an ArrayList and instantiating them correctly (with their own lifecycle in `CreateChildControls()`). I was then able to render each control in the ArrayList of `DatePicker` in the `Render()` method by invoking the ArrayList index that has not been rendered yet. 
Eg. `((RadDatePicker)datePickerArray(instantiatedDatePickersCount)).RenderControl(writer)`.

Its a dirty solution at the moment but It works for my testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a [CompositeControl](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/29/436854.aspx).  This allows you to easily add HTML markup and controls using an override of CreateChildControls and not have to think about too much else.

Some sample code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestServerControls {
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:GridWithHeader runat=server></{0}:GridWithHeader>")]
    public class GridWithHeader : CompositeControl {
        private readonly GridView _grid = new GridView();
        private readonly HtmlGenericControl _header = new HtmlGenericControl("h1");

        public string Text {
            get { return _header.InnerHtml; }
            set { _header.InnerHtml = value; }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls() {
            Controls.Add(_header);
            Controls.Add(_grid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I wont be using the `writer` styled output?

Comment: I'm just researching composite controls at the moment - didn't know they existed.

Comment: Thankyou again. I was able to use the `CompositeDataBoundControl` do achieve the desired result. I can instantiate the 3rd party controls in the `CreateChildControls()` and then `Render()` them based on `HtmlTextWriter` code and of course `controlName.RenderControl()`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a User Control (an ASCX file), which can contain other nested controls and markup.

Comment: The problem is there are too many various ways to display the data and the layout and amount of items changes are per the database and user account.